How to select PM in Vuetify VTimePicker component
I want to use the vuetify vTimePicker in my project.
However, when experimenting with the VTimePicker component at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/time-pickers/#usage, I am unable to choose PM. Nothing happens when I click 'PM', though I am able to select hour and minutes. How to select a time like 6:10 PM? Am I missing something?
.

the component is part of "Vuetify Labs" which contains their beta (not production ready) components.  I see this specific component was only added 2 months ago.  AM/PM changing is probably not yet implemented.  you can ask and/or report the issue on their github

I thought AM/PM, which is the basic functionality of a time picker would be operational even in the beta version. I do see that someone has created a bug report for this issue: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/19637

Current workaround before https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/19637 is fixed:
<v-time-picker ampm-in-title />

or config globally
createVuetify({
  defaults: {
    VTimePicker: {
      ampmInTitle: true,
    },
  }
})

